# Help in this improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

$\int_0^\infty\ln(\frac{1+x}{1-x}) \frac{dx}{x}$
can this integral be done by power series If yes I hope a full solution I dont need to use by parts

Comment: The integral doesn't converge, obviously, maybe the upper limit of integration was meant to be $1$. If you want to have your homework done for you, you might at least copy it accurately.

Comment: I cant write well in math jax I meant the abdolute value

Answer (score 2):

For $x>1$, $(1+x)/(1-x)<0$ so its logarithm would have an imaginary part.
If that is $\pi i$, the integral has imaginary part $\pi i\int_1^\infty dx/x$ which diverges.

Maybe you wanted to evaluate
$$\int_1^\infty\ln\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|\frac{dx}x$$
instead?
You can break this into integrals over $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$. In the
latter, use the substitution $y=1/x$ to get
$$\int_1^\infty\ln\left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right|\frac{dx}x
=\int_0^1\ln\left|\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right|\frac{dy}y$$
which is the same as the integral over $(0,1)$. The integral
over $(0,1)$ is
$$\int_0^1\left(2\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)\frac{dx}x$$
etc.

Comment: Thanks alot this what I meant

Comment: But in the last line is it 4 instead of 2? For the whole interval?